# Paddle will not *continue* to move, pong game, XNA

Tags: xna, c#

I'm making a pong game, and my paddles no longer continue to move after holding down the left thumbstick or dpad down. It simply moves once with each press. I think it is because I'm not checking for a LastKeyPressed anymore now that I've begun to use a new input class, which uses arrays to check for which controller is being uses, and that's not what I was using before.

**I've got to store the previous state, but I'm not sure of how to o that with these arrays.**

```
// From my input class:

  public Input()
    {
        // Get input state
        CurrentKeyboardState = new KeyboardState[MaxInputs];
        CurrentGamePadState = new GamePadState[MaxInputs];

        // Preserving last states to check for isKeyUp events
        LastKeyboardState = new KeyboardState[MaxInputs];
        LastGamePadState = new GamePadState[MaxInputs];
}

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper for checking if a button was newly pressed during this update.
    /// The controllingPlayer parameter specifies which player to read input for.
    /// If this is null, it will accept input from any player. When a button press
    /// is detected, the output playerIndex reports which player pressed it.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsNewButtonPress(Buttons button, PlayerIndex? controllingPlayer, out PlayerIndex playerIndex)
    {
        if (controllingPlayer.HasValue)
        {
            // Read input from the specified player.
            playerIndex = controllingPlayer.Value;

            var i = (int)playerIndex;

            return CurrentGamePadState[i].IsButtonDown(button) && LastGamePadState[i].IsButtonUp(button);
        }
        else
        {
            // Accept input from any player.
            return IsNewButtonPress(button, PlayerIndex.One, out playerIndex)
                    || IsNewButtonPress(button, PlayerIndex.Two, out playerIndex)
                    || IsNewButtonPress(button, PlayerIndex.Three, out playerIndex)
                    || IsNewButtonPress(button, PlayerIndex.Four, out playerIndex);
        }
    }



    // Tells the left paddle to move down
    public bool LeftDown(PlayerIndex? controllingPlayer)
    {
        PlayerIndex playerIndex;

        return IsNewKeyPress(Keys.Down, controllingPlayer, out playerIndex)
               || IsNewButtonPress(Buttons.DPadDown, controllingPlayer, out playerIndex)
               || IsNewButtonPress(Buttons.LeftThumbstickDown, controllingPlayer, out playerIndex);
    }

    // Tells the left paddle to move up
    public bool LeftUp(PlayerIndex? controllingPlayer)
    {
        PlayerIndex playerIndex;

        return IsNewKeyPress(Keys.Up, controllingPlayer, out playerIndex)
               || IsNewButtonPress(Buttons.DPadUp, controllingPlayer, out playerIndex)
               || IsNewButtonPress(Buttons.LeftThumbstickUp, controllingPlayer, out playerIndex);
    }



// And now from my Gameplay class:

public override void Update(GameTime gameTime, bool otherScreenHasFocus, bool coveredByOtherScreen)
........
input.Update();
            // Controls movement of the bats              
            if (rightBat.GetType() != typeof(AIBat))
            {
                if (input.LeftDown(ControllingPlayer))
                {
                    leftBat.MoveDown();
                }
                else if (input.LeftUp(ControllingPlayer))
                {
                    leftBat.MoveUp();
                }

                if (input.RightDown(ControllingPlayer))
                {
                    rightBat.MoveDown();
                }
                else if (input.RightUp(ControllingPlayer))
                {
                    rightBat.MoveUp();
                }


// From my bat class, so that you see what the MoveUp and MoveDown functions do:

    public Vector2 GetPosition()
    {
        return position;
    }

    public void MoveUp()
    {
        SetPosition(position + new Vector2(0, -moveSpeed));
    }

    public void MoveDown()
    {
        SetPosition(position + new Vector2(0, moveSpeed));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I see a naming issue: You're using a method named LeftDown to check if the down arrow key is currently pressed. You might want to rename it to IsLeftPlayerGoingDown or something less ambiguous like that. At first glance, I thought "LeftDown" meant it checked whether the left arrow key was down.

Now, your LeftDown / IsLeftPlayerGoingDown method checks if there was a new key or button press (during the last frame). You should just check whether it's *currently* down, not if it has just been pressed. So your code would be something like:

```
public bool LeftDown(PlayerIndex? controllingPlayer)
{
    PlayerIndex playerIndex;

    return IsKeyPressed(Keys.Down, controllingPlayer, out playerIndex)
           || IsButtonPressed(Buttons.DPadDown, controllingPlayer, out playerIndex)
           || IsButtonPressed(Buttons.LeftThumbstickDown, controllingPlayer, out playerIndex);
}
```

And you'll have to define IsKeyPressed and IsButtonPressed to check against your Current{something}State (something being Keyboard or GamePad), ignoring the Last{something}State.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm! For those who were curious, I followed his instructions, and created another helper, one for KeyPressed and another for ButtonPressed. It was nearly identical to the helper I previously had, and now checks against the current state.